# How to list files accessed by any user on Mac

Tags: macos, osx-server

I want to monitor the Mac server behaviours by listing which file or command or application on which time is opened / executed by whom. For example, another admin executed a bash command "sudo rm -fr /etc" at 10:00am, or another user opened an modified a file, or someone launched Disk Utility application.

Is there a easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BSM auditing is designed for this. See the [audit(8) man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/audit.8.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/8/audit), [this blog post from Rich Trouton](http://derflounder.wordpress.com/2012/01/30/openbsm-auditing-on-mac-os-x/), and the [Audit Explorer](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/audit-explorer/id429353921?mt=12) app.

Answer (score 1):

[fs_usage](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/fs_usage.1.html) (run as root) will tell you what's being looked at, by whom, with what and how long it's taking. If you've got access to the graphical desktop, [fseventer](http://www.fernlightning.com/doku.php?id=software%3afseventer%3astart) may also be worth looking at.

Comment: fs_usage is really helpful for looking the current file system running status.
One more question, could I collect files accessed/copied history/logs offline? for example, one file is copied yesterday, and the machine is restarted this morning, can I find it out?
Thanks,

Comment: You could constantly run `fs_usage` appending to a file on your hard drive (and, incidentally, run out of disk space in five minutes) or start digging in `/.fseventsd/` with or without the FSEvents API. I do not know of any applications that provide a frontend to historical FSEvents for their own sake.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's "Activity Monitor" will do the trick.

Open it from "Application > Utilities" folder, select process you're interested in and press Cmd-I "Inspect process".